# Plotly choropleth sliders break after converting to html with nbconvert?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python, nbconvert

I’m working on a personal project for educational purposes. Everything related to Plotly works just fine in my JupyterLab notebook. My project involves converting my notebook to an .html file via nbconverter.

### My Issue:

Now, when I convert the file to HTML, my Plotly charts are still visible, however the axis labels are all out of order. I believe this might have something to do with the data types of the columns/indexes of the dataframes being used, but I’ve tried changing them numerous times and nothing seems to be working.

For example:
This is what it looks like when I run it in JupyterLab. This is correct:
[image]

After I convert to html however, the slider seems to break and display out of order. The data still seems correct, but the slider has lost its purpose because the numbers aren't sorted. This is what it looks like:
[image]

Here is the code I used to make the sliders:

```py
    YEARS = boulder_men_all_results['Year'].unique() #list of numpy.int32

    # Slider creation
    steps = []
    for i in range(0, len(data_bal)):
        step = dict(method="restyle",
                    args=["visible", [False] * len(data_bal)],
                    label=str(YEARS[i])) #i've tried with and without the str(), but the result is the same
        step['args'][1][i] = True
        steps.append(step)
```

Here is how I generate the choropleth map:

```py
    data_bal = []
    for i in YEARS:
        data_upd = [dict(type='choropleth',
                         name=str(i),
                         locations=df.loc[i].index,
                         z=df.loc[i],
                         locationmode='ISO-3',
                         colorbar=dict(title='# of Athletes'),
                         visible=True if i == YEARS[-1] else False
                        )
                   ]    
        data_bal.extend(data_upd)
    
    # Slider creation
    steps = []
    for j in range(0, len(data_bal)):
        step = dict(method="restyle",
                    args=["visible", [False] * len(data_bal)],
                    label=str(YEARS[j]))
        step['args'][1][j] = True
        steps.append(step)

    # Sliders layout:
    sliders = [dict(active=len(YEARS) - 1,
                    currentvalue={"prefix": "Year: "},
                    pad={"t": 20},
                    steps=steps)]

    # Plot layout
    title = f"{title}<br><sup>{sub}"
    layout = dict(title=dict(text=title,
                             font=dict(size=30)),
                  geo=dict(scope='world',
                           projection=dict()),
                  sliders=sliders,
                  width=1000,
                  height=600,
                  plot_bgcolor='#f0f0f0',
                  paper_bgcolor='#f0f0f0')

    fig = go.Figure(data=data_bal, layout=layout)
    fig.show(config=config)
```

Here is the nbconvert command I used:

```py
    convert:
    jupyter nbconvert --execute \
    --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True \
    --to html "IFSC Analysis.ipynb" \
    --output docs/index.html
```

Can *anyone* offer any insight as to why this might be happening? I've been stuck on this for two days now. I don't know how, what, or why this could be occurring. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your actual data is sorted. Namely, if `YEARS` is not sorted and you iterate over the indices of it the way you are, plotly will plot it exactly in the order you ask it to.